# How to register global TypeScript Enum in Node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript

I want to make my TypeScript Enums global so I don't need to import them across my application.

What I have so far:

read-state.enum.ts

```
export enum ReadState {
    Unread = 4000,
    Read = 4001
}
```

enums.ts

```
import { ReadState } from './read-state.enum';

const enums = {
    ReadState
}

global['Enums'] = enums;

declare var Enums: typeof enums;
```

Then in index.ts

```
import './enums'; // do this once to initialize enums

var _enums = Enums; // [ts] Cannot find name 'Enums'.
```

While at runtime this might work, I'm not able to reference the enums through the `declare var Enums: typeof enums;` because the file is a module.

How can I reference this type definition without importing the module while keeping future enum definitions in separate files?

UPDATE: I also need to set the return type of a function to be the `ReadState` enum.

Based on the current selected answer I have this:

```
import { ReadState } from './read-state.enum';

const enums = {
  ReadState: ReadState
}

declare global {
  const Enums: typeof enums;
}
```

In another file I would like to set the return type on these functions but TypeScript is unhappy:

```
function getState1(): Enums.ReadState {
  return Enums.ReadState.Unread;
}

function getState2(): typeof Enums.ReadState {
  return Enums.ReadState.Read;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `declare global` block:

```
declare global {
    const Enums: typeof enums;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Ryan.

Comment: I've added more to my question. I'm having trouble w/ function return types.